# Confusion on Hashmap internal working

Tags: java, hashmap

I am not able to understand what is happening in the following code that I have written.

What I have done is, I have an Outer class `Employee` with some fields: `id,`panNo`,`name`and`address`. Then I have an inner class(it was not actually necessary to have it as an inner class) with`id`and`panNo` fields and their values are same as its outer class members.

From what I know about `HashMaps`, we use them to store key-value pairs.
The key, has a `hashcode` value, and depending upon this `hashcode` value the values are hashed.  When we retrieve a value with the help of the key, again, its `hashcode` value is evaluated and then the appropriate value is fetched.

So, `hashmap` must be some what like this:

Key -----> its hashcode | reference field--------> reference to the value object.

So when I try to insert objects with same key, then the element which is inserted the last is only available. This is because, there has to be unique keys which means a `hashcode` value should reference only one object.

Now, what I have done in my code is, I insert the `Employee` object in the map and have used `EmployeeKey` class as the key which returns the same `hashcode` value i.e 1 every time. So according to my understanding, there should only be one element in the map. But that is not happening..... I am missing to understand something.

I have written a following class:

```
 package package1;
 public class Employee {
     int id;
     int panNo;
     String name;
     String address;

     public Employee(int id, int panNo, String name, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.panNo = panNo;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
      return "Employee [id=" + id + ", panNo=" + panNo + ", name=" +   name + ", address=" + address + "]";
 }

 public class EmployeeKey {
    int id = Employee.this.id;
    int panNo = Employee.this.panNo;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        EmployeeKey other = (EmployeeKey) obj;
        if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
            return false;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (panNo != other.panNo)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private Employee getOuterType() {
        return Employee.this;
    }

  }
}
```

and there is a test class as follows:

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Employee e1 = new Employee(1, 123, "neeraj", "pune");
       Employee e2 = new Employee(2, 456, "viraaj", "pune");

       System.out.println(e1.new EmployeeKey().id);

       Map<Employee.EmployeeKey, Employee> myMap = new        HashMap<Employee.EmployeeKey, Employee>();
       myMap.put(e1.new EmployeeKey(), e1);
       myMap.put(e2.new EmployeeKey(), e2);

       System.out.println("Size:" + myMap.size());
       System.out.println("Hashcode of inner class e1: "
            + e1.new EmployeeKey().hashCode());
       System.out.println("Hashcode of inner class e2: "
            + e2.new EmployeeKey().hashCode());

        System.out.println(myMap.get(e1.new EmployeeKey()));
        System.out.println(myMap.get(e2.new EmployeeKey()));
   }
 }
```

Comment: It is not how HashMap works: one can have multiple keys with the same hash in it, as long equals method returns false. You can see the hash equality check as a quick test for equality. If 2 objects have the same hash - they will be check for equality with equals..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a hash table uses the hash code to decide which "hash bucket" to use for the key. But hash codes are not necessarily unique. There is always a possibility of collision, and this actually happens quite often.

Therefore, a proper hash table only uses the hash code as the first step to deciding where to store the element, but then it has to have some sort of collision resolution - a way to store different keys with the same hash code. This usually means that in each element of the hash table there is a linked list or a tree of actual keys.

When you put a key into the hash table, it first calculates the hash code to make the first decision. But then it uses the `equals()` method to decide whether it's the *same key* as an existing one at that position. If it is, then the new entry will replace the old, and the keys will remain unique. But if it's not the same key - `equals()` returns `false` - then despite having the same hash code, the new key will be saved separately (added to the linked list or tree).

When you want to retrieve a value by the key, then again, it will calculate the hash code as a first step, but then use the `equals()` method to compare the key with all of the keys in that position in the table (the linked list or tree). It will only return the value if the key is equal to the one that is stored. If there is no equal key, then although the hash code is the same, the key is not considered the same.

This is why it is always important to override both the `hashCode()` and the `equals()` methods together, and make sure they are calculated based on the same fields in the object.

Returning the same hash code for all objects is not going to violate the uniqueness of your hash table, but it's going to deteriorate its performance, because effectively, instead of having a hash table, that is based on one calculation of `hashCode()` and a limited number of `equals()` calls, you have one effective cell in the hash table, and your data structure has become a linked list or tree - linear search is used.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the stages to the key lookup in `HashMap`.

1. Get a `hash` of the key using `key.hashCode()`.
2. Use that hash to find the bucket that this key should have been placed in.
3. Search that bucket for the key by examining each key in that bucket using `equals` to compare the keys.

You have made `hashCode` return `1` always so all your items will be placed in the same bucket but your `equals` will still return `false` for the two keys.

```
    Employee e1 = new Employee(1, 123, "neeraj", "pune");
    Employee e2 = new Employee(2, 456, "viraaj", "pune");

    System.out.println(e1.new EmployeeKey().id);

    Map<Employee.EmployeeKey, Employee> myMap = new HashMap<Employee.EmployeeKey, Employee>();
    Employee.EmployeeKey k1 = e1.new EmployeeKey();
    myMap.put(k1, e1);
    Employee.EmployeeKey k2 = e2.new EmployeeKey();
    myMap.put(k2, e2);

    System.out.println("Size:" + myMap.size());
    System.out.println("Hashcode of inner class e1: "
            + e1.new EmployeeKey().hashCode());
    System.out.println("Hashcode of inner class e2: "
            + e2.new EmployeeKey().hashCode());
    System.out.println("Equals of keys: "
            + k1.equals(k2));

    System.out.println(myMap.get(e1.new EmployeeKey()));
```